# Spritekit PhysicsBody applyTorque

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a universal app.

I want to `applyTorque` to a Paddle

But the problem is the paddle sizes are bigger on a ipad than the one one iphone.

How can I calculate the torque to apply the same affect to the Paddle's  physicalBody?

```
SKSpriteNode *bar = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:nameImage];
bar.name = @"bar";
bar.size = CGSizeMake(PaddleWidth, PaddleHeight);
bar.physicsBody =[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:bar.texture size:bar.size];
bar.physicsBody.restitution = 0.2;
bar.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0;
bar.physicsBody.friction = 0.02;
bar.physicsBody.mass=.2;
[paddle addChild:bar];
SKSpriteNode *anchor = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(PaddleWidth, PaddleHeight)];
anchor.name = @"anchor";
anchor.size = CGSizeMake(PaddleHeight, PaddleHeight);
anchor.position = CGPointMake(bar.position.x + bar.size.width/2, 0);
[paddle addChild:anchor];

CGFloat anchorRadius = anchor.size.width/20;

anchor.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:anchorRadius];
anchor.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
CGPoint positionInScene = [self convertPoint:anchor.position toNode:self.scene];

pin = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:bar.physicsBody
                                                     bodyB:anchor.physicsBody
                                                    anchor:positionInScene];
pin.shouldEnableLimits = YES;
pin.lowerAngleLimit = -0.5;
pin.upperAngleLimit = 0.5;
[self.scene.physicsWorld addJoint:pin];
```

-(void)flip{

```
SKNode *bar=[self childNodeWithName:@"bar"];
CGFloat torque;
torque=10;
[bar.physicsBody applyTorque:torque];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the size of the paddle as a factor in the torque value:

```
CGSize paddleSize = <Initialize with paddle size>
CGFloat torque=paddleSize.width * factor; // factor will be the value you need to multiply in order to reach your desired value
```

So if for example paddle width is `100` use a constant factor of `0.05`
On the iPad the different paddle width will make the torque value to be calculated accordingly using the same factor value as above.

Comment: what didn't work? how did you calculate the torque for the ipad? did you use the same factor value as for the iphone?

Comment: CGFloat torque;
    torque=bar.frame.size.widh*0.5;   the paddle spins faster on iPhone than on iPad

Comment: I believe you will have to update the phsyics body properties that the torque relies on in the same way (e.g if the torque is affected by the body's mass then the mass should be calculated using the same technique). Its cumbersome and if you find a better way to do it I'll be happy to know about it as well...

Comment: I have found a way,I have calculate the physicalWorld.speed value and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a constant mass of the physicsBody so that the torque applied affects the paddle the same way regardless of the node's size.

```
//While instantiating the physicsBody for the "bar" node
bar.physicsBody.mass = 0.2; //This will need to be adjusted according to your needs.
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/mass):

> The mass of the body affects its momentum as well as how forces are
>   applied to the object.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really know what kind of mass would work, since there is no unit. That is based on trial and error. So has this worked?

Comment: Zemoon I have allready try it with a constant mass,but it have not affect